# Should OpenCV's HoughLines be given a std::vector or a cv::Mat for output?

Tags: opencv, hough-transform, opencv3.1

I am experimenting with **OpenCV 3.1**, specifically with the *Hough Line Transform* and the `HoughLines()` method.

Ever page of documentation and every example I have found shows `HoughLines` being given a `vector<Vec2f>` for its output. Specifically, this one (http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) shows the following two lines of code:

```
vector<Vec2f> lines;
HoughLines(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100, 0, 0 );
```

For me, this does not work at all. My code begins with some initialisation:

```
cv::Mat colourImage;
colourImage = cv::imread(argv[1], cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::Mat greyscaleImage;
cv::cvtColor(colourImage, greyscaleImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::Mat cannyEdges;
cv::Canny(greyscaleImage, cannyEdges, 50, 200, 3);
```

This works just fine. Based on the docs, I then tried this:

```
std::vector<cv::Vec2f> houghLines;
cv::HoughLines(cannyEdges, houghLines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 50, 0, 0);
```

But the result is that `houghLines` reports its size as `18446743901659714399` which is clearly bonkers - it looks a lot like memory corruption or the result of some sort of overflow.

After hitting this issue, I spent hours with Google, trying to work out if this was related to my compiler or some sort of preprocessor flags or platform or something - no answers were forthcoming.

In a moment of desperation, I guessed that it might work if I changed the last two lines to this:

```
cv::Mat houghLines;
cv::HoughLines(cannyEdges, houghLines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 50, 0, 0);
```

And that yielded a `cv::Mat` with 41 rows, 1 column and 2 dimensions per element - which seems remarkably reasonable.

Hence the question: *should* I be giving `HoughLines()` a `vector` or a `Mat` for its output? The docs suggest the former but, in practice, only the latter works so I am clearly misunderstanding something or the docs and all the code samples yielded by Google are simply wrong.

Comment: It should take a std::vector of Vec2f. Have you tried HoughLinesP ? What do your input images look like?

Comment: I have the same behaviour with both `HoughLines` and `HoughLinesP` although, when called with a `cv::Mat`, the latter returns one with dimensions 4 instead of 2. I can reproduce the behaviour with a trivial white background with some straight black lines drawn in paint, about 500px square.